# concise way to check for null or >0

Tags: c#

Being very new to C#, I'm wondering if there is a more concise way than shown below to check if `ticketID` is null or greater than 0.

```
int? ticketID = someOtherVariable;
if (ticketID == null || ticketID > 0)
{
    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: What could be more concise than this?

Comment: `ticketID.GetValueOrDefault() > 0` uses a similar number of characters. But this is code golf, not a practical question.

Comment: Not really, to make re-use easier you can always make a bool returning func out of it

Comment: @Grant That is different functionality though. OP wants *null OR greater than zero*, your code gives just greater than zero.

Comment: Same goes for @HereticMonkey's code I think

Comment: Side note: more concise is not always "better" anyway. Even if this could be shortened in a meaningful way, would it be as readable? I don't really see any problems here.

Comment: You could check for `if (!(ticketID <= 0))`, but it's less readable. I'd go for the explicit checks.

Comment: @DavidG Yeah, should be `ticketID.GetValueOrDefault(1)`. Still code golf, but not worthy of  [codegolf.se], as they have specific rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more concise way to write that would be to, inside parenthesis, use the [null coalescing operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-coalescing-operator) (`??`) to check of the value is null, with a value that's greater than zero on the right side of the operator, and then compare the result of that operation with zero.

This way, the `??` operation returns `1` if `ticketId` is null (to make our later comparison return `true`), otherwise it returns the `ticketId.Value`, which is then compared to `0`:

```
if ((ticketId ?? 1) > 0)
{
    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: Thank-you for the clear explanation of how this works.

Comment: You're welcome. Although your original code would be considered more readable, and therefore "better" in terms of maintainability. The more concise version does not really provide any benefit but may cause some confusion by future developers.